# Augmented matrixes

Tags: linear-algebra

We have the following matrix

$$  \begin{bmatrix}1 & -2 & -1 &  b_{1}  \\0 & -2 & -2 &  b_{1}+2 b_{2} \\0 & 0 & 0 & 3b_{1}+ \frac{7}{2}b_{2}+ b_{3}   \end{bmatrix}$$

which clearly does not have any solutions when $3b_{1}+\frac{7}{2}b_{2}+b_{3} = 0$. But can we not figure out more restrictions? If we continue working with the matrix, through altering with the two first rows we should be able to get that $b_{2}$ must also equal zero.

Why is $3b_{1}+\frac{7}{2}b_{2}+b_{3} = 0$ the only condition needed for this matrix to be solvable for any values on $b_{i}$?

Answer (score 0):

Let's call $x$, $y$ and $z$ the variables of your linear system.
Then, what you are asking can be reformulated as :
"Given any values of $b_1,b_2,b_3$ such that $3b_{1}+\frac{7}{2}b_{2}+b_{3} = 0$, can we find some values for $x,y,z$ such that $x-2y-z=b_1$ and $-2y-2z=b_1+2b_2$ ?"
Now, we notice that we can find some values of $y,z$ verifying $-2y-2z=b_1+2b_2$, regardless of the values of $b_1,b_2,b_3$. Then we can just choose the only value of $x$ for which we have $x-2y-z=b_1$, and we get a solution.

Therefore this matrix is solvable regardless of the values of $b_1,b_2,b_3$.